# C# - detect if windows features are turned on (particularly Windows Media Player)

Tags: .net, windows-media-player

some windows features are optional and user can decide whether he/she wants to have them off or on. 
One of them is Windows Media Player component (as described here http://support.overwolf.com/knowledge-base/enabling-windows-media-player/)

Is there a way to find out in code whether this is currently installed or not?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: `Get-WmiObject Win32_OptionalFeature | Select Name, Caption` in Powershell will list feaures, including WindowsMediaPlayer when available

Comment: It is nothing that try/catch can't do.  If WMP is essential to the program then *don't* use try/catch.  Focus instead on giving a good termination message, writing an event handler for AppDomain.UnhandledException is never optional.  People in Korea know it well and know what to do about it.

Comment: @HansPassant No, it is not the Windows media player itself which is essential. It is Windows media features which allow to use certain libraries in .NET. 
If these features are not installed, the code works without any issues but doesnt play sound for example.
So try/catch cannot do.

Comment: @RomanR.Thank you. That might do the trick as well. I will stick to registry check for now. If this solution doesnt work on 100%, I will try yours.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it the way to compare registry keys with and without these features turned on. There is number of keys, which might be equally adequate to check. 
These are the most important ones:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\wmplayer.exe
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Applications\wmplayer.exe
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AMOVIE.ActiveMovie Control
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\WMPlayer.OCX
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\MediaPlayer.MediaPlayer
```

So the actual C# code would be like

```
bool windowMediaPlayerAvailable = (Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Classes\MediaPlayer.MediaPlayer") != null);
```